# Former fonts not available in R's extrafont

Tags: r, fonts

There used to be a font named 'Segoe Script' in the extrafont() package, which I used to use extensively. Tried to use it just now in a new installation of extrafont (CRAN version) on OSX, but is no longer in the font table(). I was previously using Windows and wondered whether, since this is an MS font, that may be the reason it is not available via OSX. I would test in Windows environment, but currently do not have a PC. I should add I have ghostscript 9.22 installed, and other scripts seem to work fine.

Could someone please enlighten me? Many thanks

Comment: Aside from the package seeming to no longer being maintained (last CRAN 2014-12-08), `extrafont` only provides access to system fonts from what I can tell, it doesn't package the fonts itself.

Comment: font management in R hasn't undergone any real modernization so the pkg didn't need to be updated (FTR it's not mine). so "seeming to be no longer maintained" is not exactly accurate. The package, indeed, never came with fonts. You can prove that here: https://github.com/wch/extrafont. That particular font also is not a macOS font nor does it come with Office. You  can grab it from here — https://www.wfonts.com/font/segoe-script — but I'm fairly certain it has a more restrictive MS license and that wfonts is in copyright violation.